# Non-wordpress subdomain on Multisite Installation

Tags: htaccess

I have Wordpress multisite and I want to exclude one subdomain from multisite. I am a little bit confused. Wordpress multisite directory: /var/www/XYZ (domain example.com, subdomain: 1subdomain.example.com) Website which i want to exclude directory: /var/www/ABC (subdomain: 2subdomain.example.com

How can i exclude 2subdomain.example.com from the Multisite? There are still redirections..

Thanks for help!

Comment: Since the two directories (for the two hosts) are entirely separate, you shouldn't have to do anything. If you are seeing 3xx "redirections" then make sure you are not seeing a cached redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess you have to (make sure that you set your directory right *!^/../ABC/* )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?2subdomain.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../ABC/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ABC/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?2subdomain.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ABC/index.php [L]
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory